# How To Get CORS Response Headers On Thumbnail Image Request To YouTube Image URL

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access images returned from the thumbnail api via javascript in Chrome so that they can be painted on a Canvas.  However, I am running into a CORS block due to the fact that the the ytimg server does not provide any CORS response headers - for example - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` Other than creating a proxy in front of youtube image server and standing up my own CDN infrastructure - is there a way to get YouTube CDN so send CORS headers?  Possibly a configuration that I am missing?

Example URL: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6GeiI9DqkUQ/default.jpg

Comment: did you find how ?